# How to Connect to my local Mongodb from my online Node js IDE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ide

I am currently developing a new Api using express using an Online IDE [https://codesandbox.io/]. How do I connect to the my localhost mongodb from the online IDE? I do not have any username and password on the my local machine. If I run this I get the following error.
Error:

```
/sandbox/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:421
          throw err
          ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

The Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // Required for all expect 4.
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Express app!");
});
app.get("/v1", (req, res) => {
  res.send("V1");
});
app.post("/v1/:tenantName/getDomain", (req, res) => {
  const mainbody = req.body;
  const param = req.body.name;
  const tenantName = req.params.tenantName;
  console.log("MAIN BODY : " + mainbody);
  console.log("###############33");
  console.log(tenantName);
  let send_obj = (param || "") + "OTHER INFO : " + tenantName;

  // Mongo connect
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb2";
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created!");
    db.close();
  });

  res.send(send_obj);
});

app.post("v1/getallDomains", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Entered Api getall Domains");
  const query = req.body.query_to_execute;
  console.log("QUERY" + query);

  // Connect to mongodb
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ctanalytics_CTDemo", function(
    err,
    db
  ) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //Write databse Insert/Update/Query code here..
  });
  res.send("Final get All domains");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server started");
});
```

Comment: Its not all possible. Try to use any cloud MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngrok to create a proxy between your local mongoDB and your computer. Use your computer IP to connect from online source to mongoDB.

Make sure you're port-forwarding mongoDB ports and your firewall is allowing those rules as well.

https://ngrok.com/